# Como crear un rango dea dos numeros A y B seteados por el usuario dentro de un textfield Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Tengo un problema al crear un rango entre dos numeros "A y B" , estos los ingresa el usuario dentro de un textfield y de ahí e intentado crear el rango poniendo la salida del `textfield.toString().int()` y me da el error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
> "895202002155921101"

, tambien ya probe con `.toBigInteger()` y me aparece otro error , adjunto las capturas de pantalla para ver si alguien puede apoyarme , de ante mano muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Isaì, recuerda agregar el còdigo como texto para que sea legible para toda la comunidad.

Comment: Ok gracias para una proxima publicación lo hago así , es mi primer post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que tratas de convertir la siguiente cadena a un valor entero:

```
"895202002155921101"
```

pero debes tomar en cuenta la longitud maxima que acepta un valor entero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-types.html

El valor `895,202,002,155,921,101` no cabe en una variable de tipo `Int` pero si en una variable de tipo `Long`.

Si tratas de realizar esta conversiòn a entero:

```
   val snumero = "895202002155921101"
   val numeroInt = snumero.trim().toInt()
```

Obtendràs el error:

> NumberFormatException: For input string: "895202002155921101"

Usa `.toLong()` para que la variable pueda contener el numero representado por la cadena, de esta forma no obtendràs error:

```
   val snumero = "895202002155921101"
   val numeroLong = snumero.trim().toLong()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias , no había tomado en cuenta la longitud  esto me resolvio